# infinate loop while passing function as prop react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I followed some examples to pass function as prop.

Parent:

```
class BookList extends React.Component{
    updateBook(chosenBook){
        this.props.editBook(chosenBook); // redux func
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                {this.props.books.map((item, i) => (
                    <Book key={i} list={item} submitBook={this.updateBook(item)}></Book>
                ))}
            </div>;
        )
    }
}
```

Child:

```
<Button onClick={() => {this.toggle; this.props.submitBook(this.props.list);}}>Save</Button>
```

what I'm getting is an infinite loop, I know the problem is with parent component, any ideas/ other ways to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not passing the function correctly, you are passing a value. Remove the `()` with function name.

Write it like this:

```
submitBook = {this.updateBook}
```

See the diff here in this snippet:

```js
function abc(){
   return 10;
}

console.log('without ()', abc);

console.log('with ()', abc());
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to bind the `updateBook` method in the constructor or use arrow function.